# saving large image in grails using image-gallery plugin

Tags: grails

I am using  image-gallery plugin for my grails application. It is saving small images like size less than 2kb. but when i try to save large image, it does not save.even greater 4kb image does not save. and showing exception as below:

```
Class
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException
Message
    ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column
```

Below is my domain. which i have modified from image-gallery plugin:

```
package org.grails.plugins.imagegallery

import javax.swing.ImageIcon
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH

/**
 * Image holds the image bytes, its thumbnail and other properties related to an Image.
 * Image data field is required. Height, Width and thumbnail are created updating or creating an image.    
 */
class Image {
    byte[] thumbnail
    String caption
    String description
    byte[] data
    Integer width
    Integer height

    static mapping = {
        version(false)
        caption column: 'caption'
        description column: 'description'
        width column: 'width'
        height column: 'height'
        data column:'data',type:org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType
        thumbnail column: 'thumbnail'
    }
    static constraints = {
        description(nullable: true)
        thumbnail(nullable: true)
        caption(nullable: true)
        data(maxSize:1073741824)
        width(nullable: true)
        height(nullable: true)
    }

    def beforeInsert = {
        java.awt.Image img = new ImageIcon(this?.data).getImage();
        this?.height = img.getHeight(null);
        this?.width = img.getWidth(null);
        loadThumbnail()
    }
    def beforeUpdate = {
        loadThumbnail()
    }



      /**
        * Creates the thumbnail. Takes maxWidth and maxHeight from config.groovy if provided
        *  otherwise cosiders the default max width & height as 170 & 120 respectively.
        */
        public void loadThumbnail() {
            if (this.data) {
                def imageUtil = new ImageUtil()
                imageUtil.load(data)
                float maxWidth = CH?.config?.grails?.imageGallery?.thumbnail?.maxWidth?:170
                float maxHeight = CH?.config?.grails?.imageGallery?.thumbnail?.maxWidth?:120
                imageUtil.thumbnailSpecial(maxWidth, maxHeight, 1,1)
                this.thumbnail = imageUtil.getBytes("JPEG")
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rashedul.Rubel. Where do you try to save your image ?

Comment: As it is by image-galllery plugin.And this plugin tries to save image as byte[] in database table. i am using oracle as my database.

Comment: Do you have a constraint on your property ? If I suppose that photo is your property in your domain (ex: byte[] photo), did you add a constraint like : photo(nullable:true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2) ? (the maxSize of your array will be 2 Mo)

Comment: yes tried with photo(nullable:false, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20). i also tried with photo(nullable:false, maxSize: 1000000)// almost 1 GB. i also added mapping and given type:blob. but all were ended in vain.

Comment: Ok, could you try to use this mapping: static mapping = {
    photo(type:org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType)
} ?

Comment: I tried with this also. i am just puzzled with this problem.

Comment: Could you add the definition of your domain ?

Comment: I have added my domain @Abincepto